# Dynamic URL for ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to create a search field on the top navbar with ajax. Since it's on the navbar, it has to be present on all pages, therefore the URL is constantly changing.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: CURRENT_URL,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                search: userSearch
            },
            success: function (){...
```

I'm working with Laravel, so i tried this on the navbar page:

```
<script>
            var CURRENT_URL = "{{url()->current()}}"
</script>
```

The CURRENT_URL is displayed fine if i try to console log it, but ajax gives an error "Source map error: Error: request failed with status 404".
How can i insert the current URL into the ajax request?

Comment: what is the url printed? what you mean with "it won't work"?

Comment: The printed url is whatever page i'm currently on. For example if it's the home page then it's  http://localhost/FINAL/public/

Comment: Gives an error of "Source map error: Error: request failed with status 404"

Comment: and what if you are in other folder? if you are in localhost, you have to create a domain in the local in order to allow override of the url...

Comment: use `location.href`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use location.href instead of CURRENT_URL

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: location.href,
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                search: userSearch
            },
            success: function (){...
```

or

```
<script>
            var CURRENT_URL = location.href;
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Hopefully, this can help. Here's my approach to make my url dynamically I get the URL in every forms `var URL = $('#example_form').prop('action');` then the URL variable must append or set via Js/Jquery. check my example below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var URL = $('#example_form').prop('action');
$.ajax({
      type:'GET',
      url: URL+'/clearContent',
      beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        var TOKEN = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
        if (TOKEN) {
          return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', TOKEN);
        }
      },
      data:{
        get_category_id : $('.parent-id').val(),
      },
      success:function(data){
        if (data.response.status == true) {
          // your codes here
        }
      }, 
      dataType: 'json',
      complete: function () {}
    });
```